# Show that $x+a-[x-b],a,b\in\mathbb R^+$, is a periodic function. Find its period. $([.]$ represents greatest integer function.)

Tags: calculus, functions, fractional-part

> Show that $x+a-[x-b],a,b\in\mathbb R^+$, is a periodic function. Find its period. $([.]$ represents greatest integer function.)

**My Attempt:** Replacing $x$ by $[x]+\{x\}$, where $\{x\}$ is a fractional part of $x$.

$[x]+\{x\}+a-[[x]+\{x\}-b]=[x]+\{x\}+a-[x]-[\{x\}-b]=\{x\}+a-[\{x\}-b]$

How to proceed next?

Comment: Another approach would be showing that one can reduce to the case $a=b=0$ without changing the period.

Comment: @hardmath, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $[x]=x-\{x\}$, so
\begin{align*}
x-a-[x-b]&=x-a-(x-b-\{x-b\})=x-a-x+b+\{x-b\}\\
&=b-a+\{x-b\}.
\end{align*}
Since $\{x\}$ has period 1, our function also has period 1

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = x + a - [x - b].$

Note that $[x + 1 - b] = 1 + [x-b].$

Therefore, $f(x+1) = (x + a + 1) - (1 + [x-b]) = f(x).$